# Couldn't find [Model] without an ID - ransack - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

i'm new to rails and any help will be appreciated.

i implemented the gem ransack and whenever i click on the search button of my app i get the error stated below the image

[image]

i currently have the below error in my terminal:

```
Started GET "/adverts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Btitle_cont%5D=accountant&commit=search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-13 20:17:47 +0100
Processing by AdvertsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"title_cont"=>"accountant"}, "commit"=>"search"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Userr without an ID):
  app/controllers/adverts_controller.rb:16:in `index'
```

> i am unsure why i get the above error and why it is pointing me to the
>   index action of my advert_controller.rb and not pointing to the
>   searchpg action of my static_pages_controller.rb
>
> any help or advise on broadening my understanding to the error on this
>   will be much appreciated. i have below all my codings

adverts_controller.rb

```
class AdvertsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_advert, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @adverts = @userr.adverts.order("created_at DESC")
    respond_with(@adverts)
  end

  def show
...
  end

  def new
...
  end

  def edit
...
  end

  def create
...
  end

  def update
...
  end

  def destroy
...
  end
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

 def searchpg
    @search = Advert.search(params[:q])
    @adverts = @search.result
  end 
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :contacts,  only: [:new, :create]
  get 'contact',       to: 'contacts#new'

  resources :forms

  devise_for :userrs
  resources :userrs do
    resources :adverts
    member do
      get 'applicants'
    end
  end

  root    'static_pages#homepg'
  get     'search',                 to: 'static_pages#searchpg'
end
```

views/static_pages/searchpg.html.erb

```
<h1>search jobs</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/static_pages/approachpg.html.erb</p>

<div>
  <%= search_form_for(@search) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title_cont %>
    <%= f.text_field :title_cont %>
    <%= f.submit 'search' %>
  <% end %>
</div></br>

<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Published</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Town</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @adverts.each do |advert| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= advert.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></td>
          <td><%= link_to advert.title, userr_advert_path(advert.userr, advert) %></td>
          <td><%= advert.content %></td>
          <td><%= advert.city %></td>
          <td><%= advert.town %></td>
          <td><%= advert.postcode %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Apply now', userr_advert_path(advert.userr, advert) %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

advert attributes:

```
2.1.2 :001 > Advert.new
 => #<Advert id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, category_jobtype_id: nil, category_positiontype_id: nil, salarystart: nil, salaryend: nil, category_country_id: nil, city: nil, town: nil, postcode: nil, category_editorialapproval_id: nil, category_applicationrequest_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, userr_id: nil, category_advert_id: nil> 
2.1.2 :002 >
```

advert.rb [model]

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category_jobtype
  belongs_to :category_positiontype
  belongs_to :category_country
  belongs_to :category_editorialapproval
  belongs_to :category_applicationrequest
  belongs_to :category_advert
  belongs_to :userr
  has_many :forms
  has_many :userjs, through: :forms
end
```

Comment: Have it deliberately called is `Userr`, with an extra R?

Comment: yes, i have deliberately called my model `Userr` (user recruiter) and 'Userj` (user jobseeker)

Comment: Naming is the most important thing in programming.

Comment: yes i totally agree - i'm definitely learning along as i teach myself to develop apps in my after work hours

Comment: I've given the answer BTW!

Comment: Please post your `adverts attributes` and model code.

Comment: @Pavan i've posted the model and attributes for advert - any advise would be much appreciated...thanks